# Bootstrap Vue Table - Getting the selections from multiple tables?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I've been playing around with Bootstrap Vue and tables.

My problem is as follows: I have several tables that are dynamically loaded on a page, and users should be able to select items on each of those tables. All selections should then be concatenated into one array that I can then display at the top of the page.

So far I've added the following to each of the tables:

```
@row-selected="onRowSelected"
```

As well as the following method:

```
methods: {

            onRowSelected(items) {

                items.forEach((item) => {
                    if (!this.selectedHashtags.includes(item.hashtag)) {
                        this.selectedHashtags.push(item.hashtag);
                    }
                })

            },
}
```

The issue is that as soon as I deselect an item from the table it doesn't remove it from the array, and I'm struggling to find a way to make this work.

Unfortunately the `@row-selected` event doesn't send the ID / ref of the table, and I can't find find a method of getting all the selected rows from each individual table. That way I could just loop through all the `this.$refs` and get all the selected rows and bundle them together on every row-click.

Essentially the easiest way would be if there was a way to programmatically obtain all the selected items from a table?

Any thoughts on what the best way to achieve this might be?

Comment: Collect all selected rows for a certain table in a separate array. Add a computed prop named like `allSelectedRows` in which just return concatenated array of all array of selected rows from all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to store the selected value together with a unique key of each table. You would then call the method like with the keyword `$event` (see [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers)):

```
@row-selected="onRowSelected('table1', $event)"
```

You could also wrap an inline function in the template to achieve the same result:

```
@row-selected="(items) => onRowSelected('table1', items)"
```

Then, you would store the items in an object depending on the table key:

```
onRowSelected(tableKey, items) {
  // clears the list of this table key and overwrites it with the current entries
  this.selectedHashtags[tableKey] = items;
}
```

You can then define a computed variable to retrieve all selected hashtags (over all tables):

```
allSelectedHashtags() {
   const allSelectedHashtags = [];
   Object.keys(this.selectedHashtags).forEach(tableArray => {
     allSelectedHashtags.concat(tableArray);
   });
   return allSelectedHashtags;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! It took a bit of tweaking to get it to do exactly what I wanted, but the inline function on @row-selected was exactly what I needed, thanks!